# Microsoft Excel Password

Tags: microsoft-excel, passwords

I have two excel files that I created about a year ago. Both files are protected.

- One excel file can’t be opened/ edited without entering correct
  password.
- And in another excel file, Protect Sheet is enabled on some
  specific cells.

I downloaded some tools for recovery of both type of password but none of tools worked successfully.
Also I had gone through [Excel Password Recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/734664/excel-password-recovery).
Tool mentioned in this link did not work.

Please let me know, how to fix it?

Regards

InTech

Comment: You say "One excel file can’t be opened/ edited without entering correct password.", which is it? Can you open the file? Also, do you have any VBA experience?

Comment: It looks like you tried to use the tool in the answer to the question you linked to, but did you try the methods in the question it was marked a duplicate of? Try the answer given [here](http://superuser.com/questions/45868/recover-sheet-protection-password-in-excel) and see if that does the trick.

Comment: In what version of Excel you created the password protected file i.e. the file that won't open unless you provide the correct password in the first place?

Comment: As I mentioned, I have two excel files and I believe it was created on 2007 edition. I can't open one excel file and i can open another excel file but Protect Sheet is enabled in this file. I don't know about VBA. I downloaded some softwares but no software worked find.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I didn't get a notification. I think I have something that will help with the file you can open. Still looking into the one you cannot. I'll post an answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

For the file you CAN open, try this.

**If you do not see "developer" in your tool bar:**

Click the Microsoft Office Button  Office button image , and then click Excel Options, PowerPoint Options, or Word Options.

Click Popular, and then select the Show Developer tab in the Ribbon check box.

Press Alt+F11 (or click on Visual Basic in the developer tab) to bring up the VBA editor. 
Create a new macro by clicking on the arrow next to the button with the ruler on it:
[image: Create Module]

Copy the following code and paste it into your new module:

```
    Sub PasswordBreaker()
    'Author unknown
    'Breaks worksheet password protection.
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim l As Integer, m As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim i1 As Integer, i2 As Integer, i3 As Integer
    Dim i4 As Integer, i5 As Integer, i6 As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 65 To 66: For j = 65 To 66: For k = 65 To 66
    For l = 65 To 66: For m = 65 To 66: For i1 = 65 To 66
    For i2 = 65 To 66: For i3 = 65 To 66: For i4 = 65 To 66
    For i5 = 65 To 66: For i6 = 65 To 66: For n = 32 To 126
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Chr(i) & Chr(j) & Chr(k) & _
        Chr(l) & Chr(m) & Chr(i1) & Chr(i2) & Chr(i3) & _
        Chr(i4) & Chr(i5) & Chr(i6) & Chr(n)
    If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = False Then
        MsgBox "One usable password is " & Chr(i) & Chr(j) & _
            Chr(k) & Chr(l) & Chr(m) & Chr(i1) & Chr(i2) & _
            Chr(i3) & Chr(i4) & Chr(i5) & Chr(i6) & Chr(n)
         Exit Sub
    End If
    Next: Next: Next: Next: Next: Next
    Next: Next: Next: Next: Next: Next
End Sub
```

Ctrl+S to save, then close the VBA editor.

In your workbook, go to the developer tab and click on Macros. Select PasswordBreaker and click Run.

I've tested this in a couple different worksheets and it seems to do the trick. Your mileage may vary.